# javascript retrieve each data from firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

im using javascript with firebase, can I know how to get each data from my admin table from firebase, below is my firebase table and failed code. thx

my failed code:

[image]

my firebase table :

[image]

Comment: Never use image as your code. Paste it directly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Elvin and welcome to StackOverflow!

I think the problem is that the path you're requesting from firebase doesn't have the variable for name in it.

Try replacing:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("Admin/name").orderByKey();
```

With:

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("Admin/" + name).orderByKey();
```

I also think your iteration over the `snapshot` may be unnecessary. Try the following code to replace `snapshot.forEach()`

```
document.getElementById("label").innerHTMl = snapshot.name
```

Comment: How if I need to get the name and password value inside each user?  Thx by the way :)

Comment: `name = snapshot.name` and `password = snapshot.password` should do the trick :)

Comment: actually i want to show each name value in my html tr td using for each function, is there any function to show each value? I checked the firebase doc and not very understand. Can you teach or show me how? Thank you :)

Comment: Can you help me check is these right?

var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Admin");
 rootRef.on("child_added" , snap => {

  var name = snap.child("name").val();
  var email = snap.child("email").val();

  $("#table_body").apend("<tr><td>"+name+"</td><td>"+email+"</td></tr>");

 });